# arrow function on react hook for onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As I know putting arrow function on the jsx create a new reference of a new function every time it trigger. Like so `<p onClick={() => handleClick() />`

We can do this `<p onClick={this.handleClick />` in older react version with class, but what about using no class?

```
function Comp() {
   function handleClick() {}
   return <p onClick={() => handleClick() />
}
```

this is missing, it seems like i have to use arrow  function in the jsx again.

Comment: You could just do this? `<p onClick={handleClick}>click me</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what about using no class?

Actually it is in [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

So it should be:

```
function Comp() {
   function handleClick() {}
   return <p onClick={handleClick}>Click here</p>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like

```
function Comp() {
  const handleClick = () => {...};
  return <p onClick={handleClick} >Some clickable paragraph</p>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just pass the callback to Comp as a prop.

```
function Comp({handleClick}) {
   return <p onClick={handleClick}>Click here</p>;
}
```